# Deploying Disk Encryption Set with key vault in other subscription

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm about to deploy a Disk Encryption Set using a key in a Key vault in another subscription with Terraform.

At first deploy I always get an error that complains about different subscriptions.

This is the code:

```
# Create the key vault key used by Disk Encryption Set 01
resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "keyvaultkey02" {
  provider     = azurerm.management
  name         = var.keyvaultkey02
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv02.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 4096
  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.kv02]
}

# Create Disk Encryption Set 01
resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "des01" {
  name                      = var.des01
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group01.name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group01.location
  key_vault_key_id          = azurerm_key_vault_key.keyvaultkey02.versionless_id
  auto_key_rotation_enabled = true
  tags = merge(
    local.tags
  )
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

If I first run a deploy without the line "provider = azurerm.management" I also get the same error message but if I then add "provider = azurerm.management" back and run a new deploy it works.

So my question is how I can make it work at first deploy.

Answer (score 0):

> The error you're encountering is likely due to the fact that the key
> Vault and the resource group are in different subscriptions.

When using Terraform to manage resources in Azure across different subscriptions, you need to be careful with how you manage providers and permissions. It seems like you are using the `provider = azurerm.management` to denote that this resource should be created in a different subscription. This is the correct approach, but there are a few things you should check to make sure this works on the first deploy

Here’s a better understanding of  `provider = azurerm.management` does in the given scenario:

1. **Alias Configuration**: This line refers to an aliased provider configuration, named `management`, which is specifically configured to manage resources in a different Azure subscription. This aliased provider is declared as follows:

provider "azurerm" {
alias           = "management"
subscription_id = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" # Subscription ID of the management subscription
features        = {}
}

2. **Resource Association**: When a resource has `provider = azurerm.management`, it associates the resource with the specified provider configuration. This means that Terraform will use the `management` aliased provider to create, update, or delete that resource.
3. **Subscription Management**: By using `provider = azurerm.management`, you are instructing Terraform to create the associated resource, like `azurerm_key_vault_key`, in the Azure subscription specified in the `management` provider configuration, instead of the default provider configuration.
4. **Scoping**: It helps in scoping the resource creation to the subscription tied to the `azurerm.management` provider, allowing for the management of resources across different subscriptions within the same Terraform configuration.

**Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  # This is your main provider.
  features = {}
  # If needed, specify the subscription_id, client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias  = "management"
  # This is your secondary provider, where the Key Vault is located.
  features = {}
  subscription_id = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" # Subscription ID of the management subscription.
  # If needed, specify the client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id
}

# Assuming the Key Vault has been created in the secondary subscription, create a Key Vault key in that subscription.
resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "keyvaultkey02" {
  provider     = azurerm.management
  name         = var.keyvaultkey02
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv02.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 4096
  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.kv02]
}

# Grant the necessary permissions to the Disk Encryption Set's system-assigned managed identity on the Key Vault.
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "des_access_policy" {
  provider     = azurerm.management
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv02.id

  # This object_id refers to the system-assigned managed identity of the Disk Encryption Set.
  # Since it is not known until the Disk Encryption Set is created, a depends_on is needed on the Disk Encryption Set.
  object_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.des01.identity[0].principal_id

  key_permissions = [
    "get",
    "wrapKey",
    "unwrapKey",
  ]

  depends_on = [azurerm_disk_encryption_set.des01]
}

# Create the Disk Encryption Set in the primary subscription.
resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "des01" {
  name                = var.des01
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group01.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group01.location
  key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.keyvaultkey02.versionless_id
  auto_key_rotation_enabled = true
  
  tags = merge(
    local.tags
  )
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_key.keyvaultkey02]
}
```

Hence`provider = azurerm.management` is used to create a Key Vault Key in a different Azure subscription where the Key Vault is located, while other resources like Disk Encryption Set are created in the primary subscription. This is useful when you have resources that need to be created in different subscriptions but are related or dependent on each other, like in the case of a Disk Encryption Set and a Key Vault Key.